# Checking complexity (Big O notation)

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

On job interview I got a question:
is it true that `40^n` is `O(2^n)` I said yes because only the exponent counts and constant doesn't matter. Then I got question if `(40n)^2` is `O(n^2)`, here I feel like no, it's not because the differences for next `n` will be huge but can't formally prove it. What is the answer for both of those which won't leave any doubts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it true that 40^n is O(2^n) I said yes because only the exponent counts and constant doesn't matter.

That's a big shortcut, it doesn't work here. For 40^n to be in O(2^n), there would have to be a pair of constants c and n<sub>0</sub> such that 40^n <= c * 2^n if n >= n<sub>0</sub>. But there isn't. If you try to solve that for c, it turns out c has to be 20^n, which is not a constant. The base of an exponential cannot be ignored like that.

> Then I got question if (40n)^2 is O(n^2)

If you work out the square, you get 1600 n^2. Now there *is* a solution such that c and n<sub>0</sub> are constants, for example c = 1600, n<sub>0</sub> = 1. So yes, (40n)^2 is an element of O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of Big O:

```
f(x) ∈ g(x) if and only if |f(x)| <= cg(x), ∀x:x>=x0, for some c,x0
```

1) `40^n ∉ O(2^n)`: There is no constant c and choice of x<sub>0</sub> such that 40^x <= c2^x, for all x >= x<sub>0</sub>

2)  `(40n)^2 ∈ O(n^2)`: Choose c = 1600, x<sub>0</sub> to be arbitrary: 1600x^2 <= 1600x^2 for all x >= x<sub>0</sub>